# Issue Installing/Running WPML Plugin in a WordPress Installation (PHP) (Segmentation Fault Error)

Tags: php, wordpress, segmentation-fault

I am using [WPML Translator Plugin](http://wpml.org/documentation/getting-started-guide/) v2.4.1 on Wordpress 3.2.1. As you can see [in this image](http://i42.tinypic.com/68dh5l.png), there is no Finish or Back button on Step 3, the language switcher step. There are also no JS errors.

There is an error in the server error log each time the page loads:

`[notice] child pid <a number that changes each time> exit signal Segmentation fault (11)`

It seems its throwing this error when I have any of the languages selected; they can't find their translation file, so it causes this error. **If I don't have any languages selected, I can see the full set-up page.**

However, even when I don't have any languages selected, **if I have this plugin enabled, all my pages disappear**. When I go to view them or add a new page, I get the `Segmentation fault` error again. Deactivating the plugin causes my pages to reappear.

I should add that I am running my own server, not shared hosting.

Based off of similar (but unanswered...) issues, my .htaccess log might also have something to do with it, but it looks fine to me. It looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp-site/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp-site/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try this

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
# wp-sit base folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-site/?
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```